# Toggle Animation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to toggle the animation if I click on the button with jquery. This is the code I've already tried.

```
<div id="div1" style="height: 100px; width: 300px; background-color: black">
</div>
<button type="button" name="button">Click Me</button>


$("button").click(function() {
  $("#div1").toggle(300, function() {
    $("#div1").animate({left: "250px"});
    });
});
```

Comment: Then what is the question?

Comment: Ok., and toggle is working.. So what is your question?

Comment: I want to toggle the animation so it goes 250px to the left and then back to the default position if I click the button again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arrow891dev/q7fv1n3q/) for you, I hope it helps you:

Html:

```
<div class="holder">
<div id="div1" style="" class="div1">
</div>
</div>

<br/>
<button type="button" name="button">Click Me</button>
```

Js:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  if($(".div1").hasClass('left')){
     $(".div1").removeClass('left');
  }else{
  $(".div1").addClass('left');
  }
});
```

Css:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  if($(".div1").hasClass('left')){
     $(".div1").removeClass('left');
  }else{
  $(".div1").addClass('left');
  }
});
```